# powerBI XMLA Error deploying metadata changes

Tags: powerbi, xmla

I'm using Visual Studio (SSDT) to modeling and deploy my model to PowerBI Premium Workspace and create my report in PowerBI desktop, however now I've added new tables and applied changes on that and I'm not able to deploy it again.

**Tabular Model Designer**

*Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation*

*Cannot deploy metadata. Reason: Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'Failed to commit the metadata change, please try again later.*
Technical Details:
RootActivityId: 7c302aa2-e8d3-417f-8fb7-3bdc9969e14f

Comment: I've also tested apply these changes using the TabularEditor, but got the same error :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the last Microsoft update this issue was resolved. Now the model deploy using XMLA endpoint is working well again. Tks